# Custom validation in Sitecore xmc

Tags: xm-cloud, validation

We have a requirement to resrict  only one h1 header field in the page.so need to set up custom validation to allow only one such component having h1 header tag in it .
Can you help how  can achieve custom validations where in we need to write above logic in sitecore xmc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer here is that you can't. That level of validation is not possible.

You should use an accessibility tool like [Site Improve](https://www.siteimprove.com/) to check your pages and train the authors to build accessible content like that.

Comment: Thanks Richard. How can we add custom validation in xmc to allow only one component to be placed on the page out of 2-3 components?e.g I have a list of 3 components and I need to validate only one component is present on the page. This validation in xmc.

Comment: 2 things, that level of validation is not available in Pages, also, for new questions, please open new posts in the future, do not add them as comments to an existing question or answer. Thanks.